# Linear structural stability for maps on the real line

Tags: dynamical-systems

This might be a basic question, but I think I'm completely missing the idea of this. The question comes from Devaney's *An Introduction to Chaotic Dynamical Systems* (p.g. 59, Ex. 11)

> We define the notion of linear structural stability for linear maps by replacing the notion of topological conjugacy by that of linear conjugacy. Two maps $T_1,T_2:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are linearly conjugate if there is a linear map $L$ such that $T_1\circ L=L\circ T_2$. $T_1(x)=ax$ is a linearly stable map if there is a neighborhood $N$ about $a$ such that for $b\in N$, then $T_2(x)=bx$ is linearly conjugate to $T_1$. Find all linearly stable maps and identify all elements of a linear conjugacy class.

Now, I think I'm reading this wrong because this seems somewhat trivial to me. All linear maps on $\mathbb{R}$ are given by $T(x)=ax$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$. We have that two linear maps are conjugate if there is a linear map $L$ such that $$T_1\circ L=L\circ T_2$$ Let $T_1(x)=ax, T_2(x)=bx, L(x)=rx$ for some $a,b,r\in\mathbb{R}$. Then the conjugacy condition requires that $a(rx)=r(bx)$. Since $r\neq 0$ (it must be an isomorphism), then $ax=bx$ for all $x$, or $a=b$.

This seems to suggest that the classes are just elements of $\mathbb{R}$, but I think I'm misreading this. Maybe the question is asking for all linearly stable **continuous** maps, in which case I could use some hints since this seems like a very long and difficult exercise.

Comment: Did you actually find a solution to this? I came to the same conclusions as you.